# Choosing Hurricane Shutters

Tags: installation, hurricane-panels

In Florida, it is now officially hurricane season. I am in the market for aluminum hurricane shutters. However, I do have some questions. Home Depot offers aluminum shutters that are either 48 inches or 96 inches in height. Can the shutters be cut to the size of the window opening? Also, my windows are sunk into the opening with a concrete sill on the outside of the house showing. So it does not allow for a completely flat surface on the outside of the house on the bottom part of the window with the concrete portion that juts out. How can I secure these windows knowing that the bottom track will be difficult to mount on this jutted portion? All of my windows are like this.

Comment: A photo of the window would be helpful to visualize the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My shutters attach horizontally over the window. No track required. You may have to see a specialty hurricane shutter shop for these though. 1 tip from personal experience, spend the extra money to get aluminum shutters, they make installation much easier. It would also be in your best interest to see what types of shutters are recommended by your insurance company, and check your local municipality for permit requirements.

Comment: a photo or diagram would be very helpful to visualize your solution